# UIImageView on circular background, on a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I want to give a circular coloured background to a `UIImageView` on a `UICollectionViewCell`. To do this I am applying a `cornerRadius` to the `UIImageView`'s `layer`.

Obviously the `cornerRadius` needs to be half the `frame`'s height/width. I'm putting this code in the `layoutSubviews` method, which is probably wrong, because when it's called the image's `frame` is huge. Rotating the phone and rotating it back solves the problem, because by then the `frame` has been correctly set.

**Where should I be putting the `cornerRadius` calculation code?**

**Is there a better way of getting an image on a circular background anyway?**

Note: The `UIImageView` may change height/width during layout operations. I'm using Autolayout.

Code:

```
class EventPickerCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        print("imagesizes = frame = \(image.frame), bounds = \(image.bounds)")
        image.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(image.frame)/2
        image.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `collectionView:willDisplayCell:`?

Comment: Thanks @KyleRedfearn. I'd prefer to keep the code inside the cell however, and not require the collection view to get involved in the appearance of its cells. That's essentially why I originally overrode the collection view cell.

Comment: I think you are going to have to use the `delegate` and `dataSource`. That's what they are for

Comment: If you don't want it in your view controller, you can have your `dataSource` and `delegate` be in different files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could always just subclass a `UIImageView` in order to set the `cornerRadius` when the `frame` changes.**

```
class CircularImageView : UIImageView {
    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet { // frame did change
            self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width*0.5 // set corner radius
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. Given the lack of control that the cell itself seems to have, I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You provide the cells to the collection view controller in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`. This is where you configure the cell, so you should update the image layer here too.

If you want just a view to do this by itself, you could create a UIImageView subclass and watch for `bounds` updates:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
  didSet {
    // update layer here
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try cellForItemAtIndexPath.

You can instantiate your cell as EventPickerCell and have access to all its properties.

Another way would be to look into computed variables.

Something along those lines:
Inside your cell:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage() {
    didSet {
         imageView.image = image
         imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width
}
```

this will set the corner radius as soon as you set the cells image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd prefer however to keep the code inside the cell itself, so I can re-use it. Is there not an override of `UICollectionViewCell`?